# Why is my Redux State nested ?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing my first bigger React/Redux/Meteor App. I know that Redux is not necessarily needed in an Meteor App, but I want to use it.

I load a record from a MongoDB with Meteor and then I want to store this object in my Redux store. But the object gets nested in the store and I do not know why this is the case.

Here is my code so far:

**Action** loads the remote record

```
export const loadRecord = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        Meteor.call('loadRecord', id, (error, result) => {
             if (!error) {
                dispatch({
                    type: TYPE,
                    result
                });
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: TYPE_ERROR,
                    error,
                });
            }

        });
    };
};
```

**Reducer** should update my store

```
const initialState = {
    singleRecord: {}
};

export function singleRecord(state = initialState, action) {    
    switch (action.type) {
        case TYPE:
            return {
                ...state,
                singleRecord: action.result
            };
        default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

In more store **I expect** something like this:

```
singleRecord: {
    id:"1223",
    text:"abcde"
}
```

But what **I get** is:

```
singleRecord: {
    singleRecord {
        id:"1223",
        text:"abcde"
    }
}
```

So my store gets updated and everything is working as expected beside the fact, that my record is nested somehow.
I think I am missing a fundamental thing, or I implemented it wrong. It would be very nice if someone can explain me if this is the intended behavior or if not, can tell me why my code is not working as intended.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to unwrap the payload of the action:

```
return {
    ...state,
    ...action.result
};
```

or, in other words:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, action.result);
```

I am not sure what else you want to save in `singleRecord` but it's entirely possible you want to do this:

```
return action.result;
```

Also, your initial state should be just `const initialState = {};`

The object returned from your `singleRecord` reducer is what is stored into `singleRecord` state.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solved my problem. Forget to do the unwrapping. Also thanks for the different implementation.